# Custom oauth2 exception

Tags: java, exception, oauth-2.0

I want to Custom my own Oauth2 exception,I have search many website,but didn't find what I want.what I want is as follows: Token expired:error code is 501,Token invalid:error code is 502 and so on.what I should do if I want do this?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: what I want to ask is so much,what I need is wrap frame return message to own way。

Comment: Did you solved ?